# speeding up getting message from server using mailkit

Tags: imap, mailkit

I'm trying to fetch 50 mails or so and then call GetMessage() in a foreach loop, but it took a long time! Is there any way to speed up getting message in mailkit?
here is my code:

```
  var mailItems = folder.Fetch(startRange, endRange,MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);

            foreach (var item in mailItems)
            {
                var message = folder.GetMessage(item.UniqueId);
            }
```

after using dotTrace profiling tools for Yahoo Mails the results are as follows:

[dotTrace profiling result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zQnt.png)

Comment: Get a faster internet connection?

Comment: But the Internet connection is fast enough to perform such function

Comment: Isn't there any way to optimize the code?

Comment: How long does it take and how long do you expect it to take? What is the basis for your expectation?

Comment: What is the latency between your computer and the server?

Comment: It takes about 53 seconds for 50 mail items from inbox folder

Comment: It takes only a second or 2 for me. I suspect that you are either dealing with really large messages or you have a slow network connection to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a profiling tool such as dotTrace to try and find performance bottlenecks that you could fix to make it faster.

That's what performance profilers are for.

Comment: thanks for reply! I've edited the question and included the dotTrace profiling result.surprisingly MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.Wait() is the bottleneck. any idea?

Comment: That's not surprising at all - that method waits for the response from the server.